# Android - any way to credit a user with money? or pay into their paypal account?

Tags: android, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, android-pay

Does anyone know what the best way of crediting a users paypal account with money from an app would be?

For example: user triggers something in my app, this then takes money from my paypal account and puts it into theirs.

Is this possible from within an Android app? and if so how?
Thanks

Comment: I would take your money, if you want to get rid of it! ;)  There is a [mobile paypal SDK/API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/). Have you looked at it?

Comment: "From within an android app" sure possible, but if you start adding credentials to your app to do so, people will start paying themselves...You will need a backend for that.

Comment: @AlbAtNf haha :) I haven't looked at that yet but it sounds like it might be the right way to go!

Comment: @DavidMedenjak which backend would be ebst for this?